# У меня не запускается форма активити

Tags: android, activity, android-layout

Первый активити, там расположена только кнопка перейти. В активити, на которое я перехожу, не запускается форма. Почему так происходит? Где искать ошибку? В манифесте прописала и первое и второе активити. 
LoginPage.java:

```
public class LoginPage extends Activity {
    private static final String Login = "login";
    private static final String Password = "password";
    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
        final EditText account = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText loginIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        Button butlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        butlogin.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Please wait, connecting to server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                try {
                    String accountValue = URLEncoder.encode(account.getText()
                            .toString(), "UTF-8");
                    String loginValue = URLEncoder.encode(loginIn.getText()
                            .toString(), "UTF-8");
                    String passwordStr = URLEncoder.encode(password.getText()
                            .toString(), "UTF-8");
                    HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String URL = "http://" + accountValue + ".megaplan.ru/"
                            + loginValue + "&password" + passwordStr;
                    try {
                        String SetServerString = "";
                        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                        SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget,
                                responseHandler);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }}});}}
```

login_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:text="Название аккаунта" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="Никнейм" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:text="Пароль" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:text="логин" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите, какая ошибка в StackTrace.

Comment: Это весь лог, на переход на эту активность:
01-31 10:29:04.868: W/KeyCharacterMap(441): No keyboard for id 0
01-31 10:29:04.884: W/KeyCharacterMap(441): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-31 10:29:08.432: I/ActivityManager(60): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.test.httprequest/.LoginPage } from pid 441
01-31 10:29:09.232: I/ActivityManager(60): Displayed com.test.httprequest/.LoginPage: +672ms

Comment: Он же должен, хотя бы саму форму открыть не рабочую... там с кнопкой и edittext...

Comment: `OnCreate` переименуйте в `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Форма запустилась после того, как я пересоздала xml файл.